# How to convert string to a valid XML (with conversion) in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

How to convert simple string to a valid `XML` within `<root>` element using C#?

So if I have string `"Operation 2 > 3"` I need to convert it to `"<root>Operation 2 &gt; 3</root>"`.

EDIT: I did not express myself clear. Is there a way automatically convert special for `XML` characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this (using System.Xml.Linq)

```
XElement el = new XElement("root");
el.Add(new XText("Operation 2 > 3"));
string sXML = el.ToString();    // Result: <root>Operation 2 &gt; 3</root>
```

you just create a root node in memory and fill it with the content you want. The XElement class will take care of all the 'escaping' needed to make this valid XML text.

Comment: Your solution is ok, but I can not use it because I have Clr Function inside SQL Server. I missed reference for Libraries.

Comment: Updated my answer. I didn't know you were calling it as CLR function.

Answer (score 3):

```
string value="Operation 2 > 3";
string xmlValue= "<root>"+ value.Replace("<","&lt;").Replace("&", "&amp;")
                                                   .Replace(">", "&gt;")
                                                   .Replace("\"", "&quot;")
                                                   .Replace("'", "&apos;") + "</root>"
```

Comment: I think more of some automatic way, not simple replace? For example inside SQL Server there is a command `SELECT CAST('<root><![CDATA[' + @text + ']]></root>' AS XML);` which automatically returns `XML` with conversion of special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

using System.Xml;

```
string s = "hello";
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", s));
```

You can edit the variable s with your text.